# USB FAT32 Memory Stick was just wiped clean. Permissions denied just prior

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive

I was just scanning some images with Xsane and saving them to a USB Memory Stick. I had spent much of today doing this. I had about 200 images on this 32 GB memory stick.

Suddenly I got the message that files could no longer be saved to the Memory Stick.

I opened the memory stick folder, and all of my newest files were missing. I had been separating the files into individual folders on the memory stick. Some of them had been scanned yesterday before I upgraded Gnome. The previous files that I had saved were all corrupted. And all of the intact files on the memory stick were locked. I was getting the message that I did not have permission to view them.

I then opened gparted to see if I could recover the files. However, gparted reported that the entire partition on the memory stick was missing. I shut down the computer, removed the memory stick, and then plugged the memory stick into my old Windows 7 computer. The Windows computer reported that the memory stick was blank and needed to be formatted.

I had scanned and saved nearly 200 files to that memory stick today. The files were small and only took up a small portion of the 32 GB memory stick. But now, all of them were gone. The memory stick had previously been formatted as a standard FAT32 system.

I don't even know where to start here....

I am using Ubuntu Gnome which was just upgraded to 17.10 yesterday.

I guess the 1st thing that I need to figure out is why this happened?
Then I need to know how to prevent it?

[Screenshot Gparted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywdK5.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z242J.png)

Comment: I suggesst that you make a cloned copy of the memory stick and do repair/recovery work on the cloned copy. There are instructions and tips at the following link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986. Scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files' - PhotoRec is a last resort, it works even if you cannot repair the file system, as long as the file data are still available in the memory cells.

Comment: There noting to clone. The partition table had been wiped out.

Comment: Referencing the problems, Someone on Facebook suggested that I run a memory test. The results were showing all kinds of memory errors on my main desktop tower computer (Which I am using here now). Out of my 3 computers, this was the only one showing memory errors. I have a new set of memory cards ordered. I don't know if this will work, but it sounds reasonable.

Comment: Back to that idea about cloning the memory stick. The partition table had been removed. Gparted reported that there was nothing to rescue.

Comment: You are right about the RAM: All kinds of errors can happen, when the RAM is faulty. So it is a good idea to get new RAM cards.

Comment: Even when the partition table and file system(s) are destroyed beyond repair, there might be data to be recovered with **PhotoRec**. You cannot expect to recover the file names, but the content can be identified by file headers and saved into files in another drive. Afterwards you can identify the data by file type, use some software to open the file and check if it is a useful file or only junk. The useful files can be renamed to something meaningful to make it easy to remember (for example the original names, if you remember them). https://www.cgsecurity.org/

Comment: On recovering the scanned photos. I still have the originals and can re-scan them. The time required is irritating. On the memory, I've installed 2 new sets of chips. My 1st tests indicate that my problems are cured. But this is only the 1st tests. A memory test also showed no errors with the new chip sets. I will advise here to let you know if it is cured or not.

Comment: I'm glad it works with the nev memory cards. And thanks for sharing your results :-)

Comment: It appears that replacing a computer power supply with a larger version, and some new fans were also in the mix. But the problem seems to be solved.